# Minor edit of code rejected

Tags: discussion, rejected-edits, code

I asked a question about how to implement a [specific functionality in Rust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31101915/how-to-implement-trim-for-vecu8) and got a very [good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31101915/how-to-implement-trim-for-vecu8) that solved my problem, but I wanted to improve the [code in minor ways](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8608892). The edit was approved by the first reviewer but rejected by 3 other reviewers. The reasons reported are:

- 1x This edit defaces the post in order to promote a product or service, or is deliberately destructive.
- 2x This edit deviates from the original intent of the post. Even edits that must make drastic changes should strive to preserve the goals of the post's owner.

The first reason is not understandable at all for me, the code neither promotes anything nor it does change the algorithm or output produced by the script, what I would consider "destructive".

The other reason is a bit more understandable for me assuming the intend of the author was it to solve the problem using the exact syndactic constructs he used and rejecting syndactic sugar introduced by myself. But I doubt that using a shorthand form does not preserve the goals of the post owner.

Are edits to code generally not accepted, or is it just a mistake because the reviewers maybe do not know the Rust language?

Is it a solution to just post my improved version as a separate answer?

Comment: Code edits are rarely accepted, because people might not understand the code and won't risk it being "damaged".

Comment: Why don't you write a comment to the answerer suggesting your changes - they may have another view. Or, yes, post your own answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, changing code in edits is very rarely going to go over well.  First, changing code could affect the way the code runs and thus the correctness of the answer.  (For example, in editing you make a typo in C# code that turns an || (short circuited boolean or) into | (not short circuited bitwise or).  Oops.)  This is going to be even worse on an accepted answer because a) it is what the OP declared "works" and solved the problem specified and b) it is going to be the first one seen by anyone else looking at the question in the future.

Two, anyone moderating the edits may not know the language well enough to play "mental compiler" to make sure the before and after versions are exactly the same.  To be honest, I didn't even know Rust was a thing until I read this question.  If I saw that edit, I would have rejected it because I can't know if your edited code does *exactly* the same as the original.  Better for those reviewing edits to err on the side of caution, especially for code edits.

If you believe your edits are superior enough, add your own answer to the question, attributing to the original answerer what you took from their answer and pointing out why your answer is "better", "safer" or what have you.  If it isn't worth it, you could add a comment to the answer.

**TL/DR:** Code edits are hard to review because reviewers can't be absolutely sure that the before and after versions are the completely, perfectly equivalent.

Answer (score 4):

In my opinion since you came up with different code but you used someone else's answer to get there you should have posted your own answer with your version of the code.  Include in your answer an attribution to the answer/user that allowed you to come up with the code you wound up using.